# Can external keyboard use dvorak while internal uses qwerty

Tags: windows-8, keyboard, dvorak

Is it possible to configure so a standard external keyboard is configured so it uses Dvorak and with the inbuilt keyboard still using qwerty.

I have got both keyboard using qwerty and have successful got both keyboard using Dvorak. however i can not get it so one uses Dvorak whilst the other uses qwerty

I am using windows 8 and have added Dvorak as a language in the control panel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use two different layouts at the same time. But you can configure two layouts and switch very easy.

Shortcut: <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> for language change *(eg English to French)*

<kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> for layout out change *(eg Qwerty to Dvorak)*

Look here for detailed informations:
[Two Keyboards - two layouts](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-hardware/two-keyboards-two-layouts/cf06c0dd-2797-46e0-a596-3e33cfab20c4?auth=1)